# Only 400 steps with faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28 tensorflow object detection

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, training-data

i have a tensorflow object detection based on : [tutorial](https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10)

i annotated almost 400 picture (Samsung Gear S3), and launch train, but after 450 steps (where the classification_lost is very low 0.02) it increase too much like 25.

i don't know why i could make only few steps instead of 10000 for object detection, moreover when i launch picture detection the detection does'nt work well

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe misconfiguration, with more steps and other models it work but not perfectly